# Override a sub-class to a child-class

Tags: c++, inheritance

How does one go about overriding such a function in the example below?

It's clearly not working the way I wrote it, but is it possible to implement something similar?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class Kid
    {
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething();
    };
};

class FirstBar : public Foo
{
public:
    void Foo::Kid::DoSomething() override;
};

class SecondBar : public Foo
{
public:
    void Foo::Kid::DoSomething() override;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on it - your bars want to have `Kids` of their own, properly inheriting:

```
#include<iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    class Kid
    {
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething() {std::cout<<"Kid!\n";}
    };
};

class FirstBar : public Foo
{
public:
    class Kid : Foo::Kid {
    public:
        void DoSomething() override {std::cout<<"Kid Bar 1!\n";}
    };
};

class SecondBar : public Foo
{
public:
    class Kid : Foo::Kid {
    public:
        void DoSomething() override {std::cout<<"Kid Bar 2!\n";}
    };
};

int main() {
    Foo::Kid().DoSomething();
    FirstBar::Kid().DoSomething();
    SecondBar::Kid().DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Note inheriting from `Foo` is unnecessary unless `Kid` is defined as `protected`, but I left the inheritance in case it makes sense for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly and explains very well why my example doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to inherit `Foo::Kid`

[Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/42mowy4VaXEbHvKY)

```
class FirstBar : public Foo::Kid
```

You can inherit both `Foo` and `Foo::Kid` if you need to:

```
class FirstBar : public Foo::Kid, public Foo
```